# NestJS emit RabbitMQ event with custom payload

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs

I am integrating a NestJS "microservice" into a system that requires me to generate Rabbitmq messages with the following payload format: `{"channelId":"1ed95c30-a5ad-64ec-9aef-bbad313f5c4c"}`

NestJS docs refer to `@nestjs/microservices.ClientProxy.emit`, however it formats the payload using an incompatible convention.

Emit takes 2 arguments, `pattern` and `data`, and creates the payload with these as the top level properties.

As an example, `emit('', '1ed95c30-a5ad-64ec-9aef-bbad313f5c4c')` generates the following payload:

`{"pattern":"","data":{"channelId":"1ed95c30-a5ad-64ec-9aef-bbad313f5c4c"}}`

Is there any way to send a custom payload, or should not be using `@nestjs/microservices` for this?

Comment: Take a look to [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq).